# Is it possible to create an attribute of an instance of a Python class outside of the __init__ method?

Tags: python

All of the Python 3.x documentation that I can find implies that an instance attribute can be created *only* in the `__init__` method of a class. I have not been able to find documentation (or examples) suggesting that an instance attribute can be created in other instance methods of a class. I must be missing something, because the code example below works. I'd expect it to throw an `AttributeError`.

1. Why does this work?
2. Is it documented somewhere?
3. To me it seems like a bad feature because if, in an instance method, one were to mistype the name of an attribute declared in `__init__`, then one accidentally would be creating a new instance attribute.  Instead, I would expect an error to the be thrown to tell the programmer that they've mistyped.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_value = 1

    def store_values(self, new_value):
        self.some_value = new_value
        self.other_value = new_value + 2  # Shouldn't this be an `AttributeError` because there is no such attribute on `self`?

something = Something()
something.store_values(8)
print(something.some_value, something.other_value) # prints 8 10
```

---

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER ACCEPTED**

@Carcigenicate very helpfully points to `__slots__` as contemplating otherwise unlimited flexibility in creating instance attributes.

@jonrsharpe points to an excellent [blog post](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users) about code style in Python.

@user2357112 points to an explicit reference in [Section 9.3.3 of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).  There, an example is provided in which an instance attribute is created, briefly used, and then deleted. That example demonstrates the ability to arbitrarily add and delete instance attributes. It seems to suggest that an instance's attributes dictionary should be used like a scratchpad for holding state.

Still, I do not yet see any examples in Python documentation or tutorials that demonstrate a use case for creating instance attributes outside of `__init__` where the use case could not be achieved in a much cleaner, clearer way without the arbitrary attribute creation. I'm hopeful that someone reading this will point out a good use case or two.

The Python Wiki's entry on [UsingSlots](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots) discusses some aspects of the under-the-hood workings of `__dict__`.  It observes, "The `__dict__` attribute is a dictionary whose keys are the variable names and whose values are the variable values. This allows for dynamic variable creation but can also lead to uncaught errors. For example, with the default `__dict__`, a misspelled variable name results in the creation of a new variable, but with `__slots__` it raises in an `AttributeError`."

It is worth noting that the code example given, above, only works if the `store_values` method is called before trying to access the value of the extra attribute. So, for example, if the next-to-last line is removed, the last line will raise an `AttributeError`.  For an inexperienced Python user (me), debugging that scenario was very confusing.  Sometimes the method creating the extra attribute was being called, so the extra attribute was present, and subsequent code that relied upon that attribute worked just fine.  Other times the method was not called, so the extra attribute was not created, and the subsequent code crashed.

Best practice: confine instance attribute declarations to `__init__`.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be an attribute error; you've _created_ that attribute on `self`. It's generally good practice to create relevant attributes in `__init__`, but not _required_ - [we're all responsible users](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users).

Comment: You are completely wrong.  You can create an instance attribute in any method, or even outside the class.  So, you could do `something.wild = 'abcde'`.

Comment: If you look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), you'll see that they create an attribute outside `__init__` right in the tutorial.

Comment: @user2357112, I've just scanned through Section 9 of the tutorial, but I'm not seeing any case of an instance attribute being created outside of an __init__ method.  Could you please point me to the subsection in which that occurs?

Comment: @MatthewRips: Section 9.3.3.

Comment: There are lots of instances where a typo can mess you up at runtime.  Using a linter and a static type checker protects you from most of them.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112.  That example surely does demonstrate the intent.  It seems to me that that example is meant to demonstrate the dynamic nature of instance variable declaration and deletion.   But, is there a motivation for writing code like the example in Section 9.3.3? That leads me to a different question: why do we have a statement capable of deleting instance attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance attributes can be created wherever; even outside of the class.

Unless you specify a `__slots__` class attribute, the class instances are just backed by a dictionary, and can take on any attribute you want, at any time.

If you want bad attribute assignments to be an error, specify a [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

```
class Something:
    __slots__ = ['some_value']

    def __init__(self):
        . . .
```

Not only does this make the class less error-prone, it has some performance benefits as well.

Comment: Thank you, @Carcigenicate.  That's a great answer.  I see how the `__slots__` documentation implies the possibility of my example.  ...  I've spent a fair amount of time scouring the documentation for an explicit reference to the concept.  The closest I've found is in [Section 7.2 Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).  Are you aware of any documentation that explicitly states the intent that the creation of instance attributes is totally unrestricted, that it can be done via an assignment statement in any context?

Comment: Never mind on that last question.  The comments, above, led to Section 9.3.3 of the tutorial.